# Help with hand tossed pizza dough (like domino's)

Tags: bread, dough, pizza

I keep fresh dough ball in the refrigerator for 6 days to slowly ferment. I bake pizza in conventional oven at 245C for 6 minutes.  On the 1st and 2nd days they bake perfectly, but I start to have problems on the 3rd through 6th days. They rise well, and stretch well, but do not bake at all. I use [CMC powder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboxymethyl_cellulose) for preserving dough moisture. I work the dough well. How can I improve baking on days 3–6?

Comment: 245c (475F) seems kind of low for pizza, what is cmc powder ?

Comment: Are you using the same dough over six days?

Comment: @Max not in a home oven, most pizza recipes I've seen call for 425*F through 475*F, although yes, it would taste better cooked at higher temp for shorter time... that's just not always possible in a home oven.

Comment: @Stephie I read it like that. Also, CMC powder I think OP means Cornmeal Powder, often used to lubricate the dough on a pizza board (although I've never heard of it being used to preserve moisture).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "not bake at all"?  Do you mean it didn't bake well, or stayed soft, or was doughy, or actually remained the same floppy dough you put *in* the oven?  If I put dough in a hot oven, I'd expect it to firm up, brown, and eventually blacken - I can't think of any way a dough could just...not cook, though I can think of ways for the product to not be what was expected/wanted.  More information on what specifically was going on that you didn't like in the dough would help us figure out the causes.

Comment: Um... Domino's does not hand-toss their dough. They use a roller.

Comment: SnakeDoc: CMC Powder is not cornmeal.  It's Carboxymethyl cellulose, a gum additive.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that a dough made to last 6 days of refrigerated fermentation should be different that one made to be baked after 24 or 48 hours.

If you use a stronger flour (W=350) your dough will be great after 5-6 days, but not perfect before; to have a great dough after 24 hours you should use a medium flour.

If your flour does not indicate the W value (that can roughly be considered proportional to the protein level) try adding a bit (1/3) of Manitoba Flour to your next dough (but consider that it will be less good the first day)